# Problems with datatype size in database

Tags: java, database, grails, enums

Is there any solutions to let me set companyType into size (10) in database ? I have defined the size of my companyType in constraints but it seems that it doesn't work at all. In database, it is still showing my companyType type is varchar(255).

```
//Domain File
String hostRef
String loginId
String state
CompanyType companyType



static constraints = {
    hostRef(size: 1..20, nullable: true)
    loginId(size: 1..20, nullable: true)
    state()
    companyType(size: 1..10, nullable: true)

}

// Enum
public enum CompanyType {
SOLEPROVIDER(1)

CompanyType(int value) {
    this.value = value
}

private final int value

int getValue() {
    value
}
```

}

Comment: Never had the idea to add a size constraint to a enum since the enum kind a takes care that the right data goes in and out. However, one thing you should check is that your dbCreate is 'create' since hibernate does not perform updates that might cause data loss, truncation in this case. Re-create the database using grails and see if you get your size there this way. This could be your problem since maybe you added that constraint afterwards, when hibernate already made the table once.

Comment: have you tried to create a custom validator instead?

Answer (score 1):

For a new DB field you can map the field to a `varchar(10)` (see "Database Mapping" in the Grails User Documentation for your version of Grails). This should create a `varchar(10)` field in the DB.
If you want to change the type after it is already created you either have to change it in the DB or via a Database Migration script.

If you use the Database Migration-Plugin then you can let the Plugin create a script (for creation or update of the field) an adjust it manually.

### Personal comment

Ask yourself if it's worth the effort of adding this constraint instead of working with the default. If you ever add an enum value to `CompanyType` that is more than 10 characters long then you have to extend your DB type. If you can guarantee that it will never (under no circumstances) be longer than 10 characters then it may be worth the effort.

> "The real problem is that programmers have spent far too much time worrying about efficiency in the wrong places and at the wrong times; premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of it) in programming." – Donald Knuth